# HLSL shader doesn't work

Tags: directx-11, hlsl

I've made two shaders that share almost all the code except for a line that shouldn't change the result.
That's the shared part of code:

```
struct VOut
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR;
    float4 ld1 : LD;
};

 cbuffer LIGHT : register (cb0)
{
    float4 light_direction;
    float4 light_color;

};

cbuffer TRANSFORMATION_MATRIX : register (cb1)
{
    float4x4 transformationMatrix;
};

cbuffer CAM_PROJ_MATRIX : register (cb2)
{
    float4x4 cameraProjectionMatrix;
};

float4 PShader(float4 position : SV_POSITION, float4 color : COLOR) : SV_TARGET
{
return color;
}
```

The part that changes is the vertex shader:

```
 VOut VShader(float3 position : POSITION, float4 color : COLOR)
 {
    VOut output;

    float4 rpos = mul(transformationMatrix,float4(position, 1.0));

    output.position = mul(cameraProjectionMatrix, rpos);

    *output.ld1 = light_direction;*

    output.color = color;

    return output;
}
```

This one works fine, but if I change the line between asterisks (obviously the asterisks are not in the real code) to:

```
output.ld1 = float4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
```

then I don't see anything on the screen. How's this thing possible?

Comment: ``LD`` is not a standard semantic, so it doesn't have any meaning. Try using ``TEXCOORD0`` to get a valid inter-stage interpolator.

Answer (score 0):

```
  struct VOut
    {
        float4 position : SV_POSITION;
        float4 color : COLOR;
        float4 ld1 : TEXCOORD0;
    };
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.